# Локализация строк в Си

Tags: c, локализация

Работаю над приложением на Си. Важным вопросом есть локализация строковых ресурсов. Существуют ли специальные библиотеки или инструменты для выполнения такой цели?

Comment: Можно использовать [gettext](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/) система написана на C

Comment: Чем вас не устроили варианты, которые находятся на расстоянии одного клика в гугляндексе? И в чём по-вашему особенность языка C в этом контексте?